# In EasyAdmin 3 configureActions method how do I get the current entity?

Tags: easyadmin

I wish to add an action to another to the index action with a predefined filter.

To build the filter I need the get current entity in the configureActions method.

```
    public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
    {
        parent::configureActions($actions);

        $adminUrlGenerator = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);
        $url = $adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SiteCrudController::class)
            ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
            ->set('filters', [
                'agent' => [
                    'comparison' => '=',
                    'value' => 2194, // How to get current entity here??
                ]
            ])
            ->generateUrl()
        ;

        $viewRelatesSites = Action::new('viewRelatedSites', 'Sites', 'fa fa-file-invoice')
            ->linkToUrl($url)
        ;

        $actions->add(Action::DETAIL, $viewRelatesSites);
        $actions->add(Action::EDIT, $viewRelatesSites);

        return $actions;
    }
}
```

How can I get the entity here?

Answer (score 3):

After a day looking for the current entity into my AbstractCrudController, I found this :

```
$currentEntity = $this->getContext()->getEntity()->getInstance();
```

Comment: What's weird is I found this way to do only once in the [symfony documentation](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/current/actions.html#adding-custom-actions).

So please, feel free to give more informations if this is a bad practice.

Answer (score 2):

To get the current entity the AdminContext is needed.

The best place to get this with the entity set is in a BeforeCrudActionEvent.

```
final class AgentCrudActionEventListen implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator;

    private AdminContextProvider $adminContextProvider;

    public function __construct(AdminUrlGenerator $adminUrlGenerator, AdminContextProvider $adminContextProvider)
    {
        $this->adminUrlGenerator = $adminUrlGenerator;
        $this->adminContextProvider = $adminContextProvider;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            BeforeCrudActionEvent::class => 'onBeforeCrudActionEvent',
        ];
    }

    public function onBeforeCrudActionEvent(BeforeCrudActionEvent $event): void
    {
        $crud = $event->getAdminContext()->getCrud();

        if ($crud->getControllerFqcn() !== AgentCrudController::class) {
            return;
        }

        $entity = $this->adminContextProvider->getContext()->getEntity();
        if (!$entity) {
            return;
        }

        $url = $this->adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SiteCrudController::class)
            ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
            ->set('filters', [
                'agent' => [
                    'comparison' => '=',
                    'value' => $entity->getPrimaryKeyValue(),
                ]
            ])
            ->generateUrl()
        ;

        $viewRelatedSites = Action::new('viewRelatedSites', 'Sites', 'fa fa-file-invoice')
            ->linkToUrl($url)
        ;

        $actions = $crud->getActionsConfig();

        $actions->appendAction(Action::DETAIL, $viewRelatedSites->getAsDto());
        $actions->appendAction(Action::EDIT, $viewRelatedSites->getAsDto());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since EasyAdmin 3 events are discouraged [per the docs](https://symfony.com/bundles/EasyAdminBundle/3.x/events.html):

> Starting from EasyAdmin 3.0 everything is defined with PHP. That's why it's easier to customize backend behavior overloading PHP classes and methods and calling to your own services. However, the events still remain in case you want to use them.

```
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    // Create your action
    $viewRelatedSites = Action::new('viewRelatedSites', 'Sites', 'fa fa-file-invoice');

    //set the link using a string or a callable (function like its being used here)
    $viewRelatedSites->linkToUrl(function($entity) {
        $adminUrlGenerator = $this->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class);
        $url = $adminUrlGenerator
            ->setController(SiteCrudController::class)
            ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
            ->set('filters', [
                'agent' => [
                    'comparison' => '=',
                    'value' => $entity->getId()
                ]
            ])
            ->generateUrl();
        return $url;
    });
    
    $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $viewRelatedSites);
    
    return $actions;
}
```